# errors shown like "{{attribute}} {{message}}" rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something happen and now my errors are displayed like "{{attribute}} {{message}}".

For example:

```
<% form_for(@usuario) do |f| %>
  <% if @usuario.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
      <br />
      <h2><%= @usuario.errors.count %> errores encontrados:</h2>
      <br/>
      <ul>
      <% @usuario.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <p>- <%= msg %></p>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
      <br/>
    </div>
  <% end %>

.
.
.
<%end%>
```

shows the errors message like:

```
1 errores encontrados:

    - {{attribute}} {{message}}
```

Why? What did I do wrong?

Thx.

**RESOLVED:**
I did a rails upgrade from 2.3.8 to 2.3.9...

> gem install -v 2.3.9 rails
>   And that solve it!!! =)**
>   --include-dependencies

Answer (score 4):

You have an incompatible version of the i18n gem. Try downgrading to a lower version.

Comment: Can you please help me with that? What should I do?

Comment: sure. Run in terminal: 'gem install i18n -v=0.4.0' then in your config file, include the line "config.gem i18n, :version => '=0.4.0' "